# Rundeck - Get in the script the username who executed the job

Tags: rundeck

I would like to know if there is a way to get the username who executed the job and use it in the job which has been executed ?

If my question isn't clear, here is an example :

An user 'bobby' connects to rundeck and execute the job 'lets_go_to_the_moon'
In the job 'lets_go_to_the_moon' I want to get 'bobby' in a variable and use it to store this information in a database for example.

Ps : I know that this information can be retrieve in the database dedicated to rundeck, but is there a native variable dedicated to get this kind of information ? And if yes, how ?

Thank you guys,
Happy day !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `job.username` context variable.

Command step format: `${job.username}`

Inline-script format: `@job.username@`

"External" script format: `$RD_JOB_USERNAME`

If you are dispatching an "external" script to a remote node, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#passing-environment-variables-through-remote-command).

[Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#context-variables) you can see all context variables available.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro ;)
I would loved to upvote your answer but I didn't have enough reputation :(

Comment: No worries! Happy to help  :-)

Comment: Also, do you know if it's possible to get the logged username and put it in a "remote URL allowed value" option type ? The goal is to send the info to a web service. I've tried to put the 3 variables format you've shared (${job.username} / @job.username@ / $RD_JOB_USERNAME) but none of them returns me the name of the logged user

Comment: A good way to send info to a web service is to use the HTTP workflow step plugin: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-step you can use ${job.username} on any plugin parameter.

Comment: Hi MegaDrive68k, thanks for this share, I will surely install it ! But my goal here is to create a dynamic option with information got from a WS and with the rundeck logged user in parameter for the WS. If I pass thought a step, nothing will change in the job options.

Comment: Well, I found my answer by myself ^^ 
If it can help anyone else, you have to use this variable in your job option : ${job.user.name}

Comment: Amazing! Good news then :-)

Comment: The last link is dead, but a  backup can be found here https://web.archive.org/web/20210728003530/https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#passing-environment-variables-through-remote-command

Comment: Link update with the "new" docs entry: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#passing-environment-variables-through-remote-command thanks :)